# Bring composite deck back to life

Tags: deck, decking, refinishing, composite

Is there a way to enhance the look of a composite deck ? This deck was built 5 years ago and looks little worn out.
To make matters worse there were some paint droplets on the deck and i used a metal brush to scrape them off but it left scars on the deck.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Asking about refurbishing the scrape marks from paint removal is one thing, but "bring it back to life" is rather vague and open ended... Also, some close up pics of the areas of concern would probably be helpful. That said, the simple answer is "replace the damaged boards", but that's probably not the answer you're after...

Comment: You need to know exactly what product was used and when it was manufactured in order to find and read the manufacturer's recommendations on how to clean or refurbish the finish.   It varies by manufacturer, by product line, and by year of manufacture.

Comment: A better approach to removing paint drops is using a paint stripper chemical.  It would not affect a plastic surface.